# secure verification process between android app and server

Tags: android, security, webserver

I am writing an android application which will not be available by the google play store. I am looking into how can I accomplish to verify that any user of the application is indeed a verified user.

I would like to use a server for this process that the application is using anyway to send/receive data. My idea was setting up something like a challenge that only verified clients would be able to pass. So anyone using a fake app will not be able to bypass this.

Is there any standard approach to this problem? I have searched a bit but did not find something covering this entirely. Please keep in mind that I am aware of the fact that given the fact the application runs on an android phone which is a device out of my reach there will probably always be ways to bypass the challenges. I am looking to see what the majority is doing in these cases.

Comment: This is not possible, you can't authenticate the app. Anything an app may have is available for users to create another app.

Comment: so there is not way this can be done?

Comment: Not in a way that would be considered reasonably secure if by secure you mean it's impossible (or at least very hard) to create a "fake" app. You can make it somewhat harder, but determined attackers will always be able to do so. The trick is, 99.99% of the times they don't actually want to.

Comment: So what do big companies actually do in order to fight off fake apps?

Comment: They publish great apps that nobody can exceed in a reasonable cost, mostly. Also they add legal clauses I guess so that they can take action if somebody made a fair attempt at another app.

Answer (score 2):

There are two probable issues here. First is user authentication (authn) and authorization (authz), and the second is verifying that the client app itself is authentic.

For user authn/authz, I would use some form of OAuth2 with OpenID/Connect. The end result is that you are authorizing your client app to access your end resources on behalf of the user. There are open source and free commercial services available to get you started.

More problematic is authentication of the app itself. API keys are the standard approach here, but these are static secrets which don't do much good if the app is tampered with or the key is observed in the communications channel. No matter how hard you try to hide or compute the secret as needed, if your endpoint is valuable enough, someone will do the work necessary to extract and abuse the secret and then your backend.

You are on a good track thinking about some form of challenge-response protocol. Captchas are the canonical approach here, but they are quite annoying to users on a mobile app and are not always very effective. I believe (and full disclosure, so does my company) that attesting the app's authenticity through a cryptographically secure challenge is a solid strategy. The attestation service challenges the app and analyzes its response. The challenge evaluates whether the app's code has been tampered with and assesses the state of the runtime (is app rooted? running in a debugger? frameworks like frida or xposed present? etc.). The app is issued a short-lifetime token - properly signed if the attestation passes, invalid otherwise. There's no secret in the app, and the app does not make the authentication decision; it just passes on the token to your backend which checks the token lifetime and signature to determine the app authenticity. No token or invalid token and you know this is a bot or tampered app.

For background on user and app authenticity, check out a 3 part blog post, starting with [Mobile API Security Techniques](https://hackernoon.com/mobile-api-security-techniques-682a5da4fe10), or if you prefer video, check out [A Tour of Mobile API Underprotection](https://hackernoon.com/a-tour-of-api-underprotection-2ad86fc5ce48). I encourage you to also check out [approov.io](https://approov.io) for how this can be implemented as a service.